# How to pass List<DerivedClass> when param type is List<BaseClass>?

Tags: c#, derived-class, generic-list, ref

How can i pass a list which is a list of DerivedObjects where the Method is expecting a list of BaseObjects. I am converting the list `.ToList<BaseClass>()` and am wondering if there is a better way. My second problem is the syntax is incorrect. I am trying to pass the list byref and i am getting an error: `'ref' argument is not classified as a variable`

How can I fix these two problem? thanks.

```
public class BaseClass { }
public class DerivedClass : BaseClass { }

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<DerivedClass> myDerivedList = new List<DerivedClass>();
        PassList(ref myDerivedList.ToList<BaseClass>());
// SYNTAX ERROR ABOVE IS - 'ref' argument is not classified as a variable

        Console.WriteLine(myDerivedList.Count);
    }

    public static void PassList(ref List<BaseClass> myList)
    {
        myList.Add(new DerivedClass());
        Console.WriteLine(myList.Count);
    }
}
```

**Solved:**

A method similar to this has solved my issue.

```
public static void PassList<T>(ref List<T> myList) where T : BaseClass
{
    if (myList == null) myList = new List<T>(); 
    // sorry, i know i left this out of the above example.

    var x = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), new object[] {}) as T;
    myList.Add(x);
    Console.WriteLine(myList.Count);
}
```

Thank you to all who help across this question and from other SO questions.

Comment: Why do you need `ref` in this case?

Comment: ref is required otherwise the added items remains boxed with the method. (hope i got those terms right).

Comment: `List` **is** a reference type class. The items added in the method will be added to the same instance.

Comment: @Valamas: No, you don't understand how `ref` works (or possibly how reference types work). Follow the link in my answer and read it *really carefully*.

Comment: I had not seen the "where T : BaseClass" syntax before, which is useful.  Thanks for posting the solved code.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The `ref` part is easy: to pass an argument by reference, it has to be a variable, basically. So you can write:

```
List<BaseClass> tmp = myDerivedList.ToList<BaseClass>();
PassList(ref tmp);
```

... but that *won't* affect either the value of `myDerivedList` or contents itself.

The `ref` here is pointless anyway, as you're never changing the value of `myList` within the method anyway. It's important to understand the difference between changing the value of a parameter and changing the contents of the object that the parameter value refers to. See [my article on parameter passing](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/parameters.html) for more details.

Now as for why you can't pass your list in - it's to preserve type safety. Suppose you *could* do this, and we could write:

```
List<OtherDerivedClass> list = new List<OtherDerivedClass>();
PassList(list);
```

Now that would be trying to add an instance of `DerivedClass` to a `List<OtherDerivedClass>` - that's like adding an apple to a bunch of bananas... it doesn't work! The C# compiler is preventing you from performing that unsafe operation - it won't let you treat a bunch of bananas as a fruit bowl. Suppose we *did* have `Fruit` instead of `BaseClass`, and `Banana` / `Apple` as two derived classes, with `PassList` adding an `Apple` to the list it's given:

```
// This is fine - you can add an apple to a fruit bowl with no problems
List<Fruit> fruitBowl = new List<Fruit>();
PassList(fruitBowl);

// This wouldn't compile because the compiler doesn't "know" that in PassList
// you're only actually adding an apple.
List<Apple> bagOfApples = new List<Apple>();
PassList(bagOfApples);    

// This is the dangerous situation, where you'd be trying to really violate
// type safety, inserting a non-Banana into a bunch of bananas. But the compiler
// can't tell the difference between this and the previous one, based only on
// the fact that you're trying to convert a List<Banana or Apple> to List<Fruit>
List<Banana> bunchOfBananas = new List<Banana>();
PassList(bunchOfBananas );
```

C# 4 allows *generic variance* in certain situations - but it wouldn't help in this particular case, as you're doing something fundamentally unsafe. Generic variance is a fairly complicated topic though - as you're still learning about how parameter passing works, I would *strongly* suggest that you leave it alone for the moment, until you're more confident with the rest of the language.

Comment: Cheers Jon for the explanation and link to your website. I have solved my problem using generics.

Comment: Can I ask what `List<BaseClass> tmp = myDerivedList.ToList<BaseClass>();` does exactly? Does it create a copy or what? I have a similar need, and--to my surprise--if I do this and pass the result to my method, changes made to the objects are reflected in the original list. (I am modifying the objects, not adding or removing anything from the list.)

Comment: @JonathanWood: It creates a shallow copy of the list. So changes to the original list in terms of additions and removals will *not* be seen in the copy, but changes to the objects will - because the new list contains references to the same objects.

Answer (score 5):

If you must keep the `ref`, you can do this:

```
var list = myDerivedList.ToList<BaseClass>();
PassList(ref list);
// SYNTAX ERROR ABOVE IS - 'ref' argument is not classified as a variable
```

For a `ref` parameter, it needs a variable to *reference*.  When created on-the-fly there's nothing to reference later in code so it really makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

First, in the code you provided you don't need the `ref` because you don't really change the *destination* (reference) myList in any way.
Then of course you get an error with the `ref myDerivedList.ToList<..>()` because with a byref you can change where a variable is pointed to, but you don't give a variable, you give a *value* (so just read the compiler complain ;) )

To you point: read about [Co- and Contravariance](http://blog.t-l-k.com/dot-net/2009/c-sharp-4-covariance-and-contravariance) - if you are using .net 4.0