# Polymorphism while iheriting generic class

Tags: c#

Let's consider that there is an abstract base class and one, or more child classes:

```
public abstract class BaseInnerClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class ConcreteInnerClass : BaseInnerClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Then, let's assume there is a generic abstract class that has a property of above abstract class type:

```
public abstract class GeneriAbstractTestClass<T> where T : BaseInnerClass
{
    public T InnerClass { get; set; }    
}
```

Then let's make a class that inherits from the class above:

```
public class ConcreteTestClass : GeneriAbstractTestClass<ConcreteInnerClass>
{
    public string ConcreteString { get; set; }
}
```

So now everything is prepared to ask a question ;) Why it is not possible to do it:

```
 //cannot convert initializer type
 GeneriAbstractTestClass<BaseInnerClass> genericClass = new ConcreteTestClass();
```

while this is allowed:

```
 //ok
 BaseInnerClass baseInner = new ConcreteInnerClass();
```

What's the difference between this two assignments?

Comment: Simply put, a `GeneriAbstractTestClass<BaseInnerClass>` isn't a `GeneriAbstractTestClass<ConcreteInnerClass>` or vice versa, just like a `List<Apple>` isn't a `List<Fruit>`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7643211/how-to-pass-listderivedclass-when-param-type-is-listbaseclass/7643257#7643257 - not sure whether this *quite* counts as a duplicate, but it's very close.

Comment: I think it will helpful for you to read it: [real world example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2662369/covariance) and [covariance-contravariance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This has nothing to do with abstract classes. A simpler example would be

```
List<BaseInnerClass> base = new List<ConcreteInnerClass>
```

The fact that type `A` is derived from type `B` does not imply that type `C<A>` is derived from type `C<B>`. Your example is a little bit more complicated, but it can be explained using the same logic.

Note that you can define another concrete type:

```
public class EvilConcreteInnerClass : BaseInnerClass
{
}
```

If what you wanted was possible, then the following would work:

```
GeneriAbstractTestClass<BaseInnerClass> genericClass = new ConcreteTestClass();
genericClass.InnerClass = new EvilConcreteInnerClass(); // OK, because the compiler sees `T` as `BaseInnerClass`
```

`genericClass` variable points to an object whose `T` generic parameter is `ConcreteInnerClass`, so assigning `EvilConcreteInnerClass` to the property would result in a run-time exception.

Answer (score 0):

Actually. You can do this. But you need to specify interface with covariant **out T** generic, because it is type safe to make those casts.

**Example**

```
namespace ConsoleTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var a = new Generic<Concrete>();
            IGeneric<Base> c = new Generic<Base>();
            c = a;
        }
    }

    public interface IGeneric<out T> where T: Base
    {
        T Inner { get; }
    }

    public class Generic<T> : IGeneric<T>
        where T : Base
    {
        public T Inner { get; set; }
    }

    public class Concrete : Base
    {
    }

    public class Base
    {
    }
}
```

Delegates also not restricted if they specify covariant out generic templates.

It means those casts you want is OK as long as you use **readonly generic properties**. So, like @Kapol said and provided you example why it is not type safe to allow setters on properties or pass T into function.

**Summary**

Use ReadOnly interfaces if you want to use those kinds of casts.

Comment: Classes cannot be covariant, and that's what the question is dealing with.

Comment: I aggree, but it is just by design in C#. Nothing more. For example in C++ you can create covariant class with use of consts.

Comment: And yet this isn't C++.

Comment: I thought it would be usefull to mention C++ syntax for wider picture.