# Error implementing an abstract method

Tags: c#, derived-class

I'm trying to define a base class like this

```
public abstract class EntityBase
 {
 // some other things here
     public abstract BindingList<EntityBase> BindingList();
 }
```

When I define a derived class

```
public class SomeEntity: EntityBase
 {
     public BindingList<SomeEntity> BindingList()
     {
         BindingList<SomeEntity> result = new BindingList<SomeEntity>();
         // code to populate the list
         return result;
     }
  }
```

the compiler says:

> 'AbstractDataContext.SomeEntity' does not implement inherited abstract member 'AbstractDataContext.EntityBase.BindingList()'

Obviously, the problem is that the compiler can not solve SomeEntity **is** EntityBase, and therefore (IMHO) should satisfy the abstract definition, so the method return does not match the definition in the base class.
How can the derived class satisfy this requirement?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7643211. Just because a `SomeEntity` is a `SomeBase` doesn't mean that a `BindingList<SomeEntity>` is a `BindingList<SomeBase>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function needs to return `BindingList<EntityBase>` to satisfy the contract. Otherwise it is a different function signature. However, since SomeEntity is a decendant of EntityBase you can return a `BindingList<SomeEntity>` that is upcast to a `BindingList<EntityBase>`. But the signature of the function has to match.

Also, you need the `override` keyword in the method signature of the SomeEntity class:

```
public override BindingList<EntityBase> BindingList()
```

Comment: But have you changed the method signature in SomeEntity to `public BindingList<EntityBase> BindingList()`?

Comment: protected BindingList<EntityBase> upCast( BindingList<SomeEntity> source)
        {
            BindingList<EntityBase> result = new BindingList<EntityBase>();
            foreach (SomeEntity ety in source)
                result.Add(ety as EntityBase);
            return result;
        }

        public BindingList<EntityBase> BindingList()
        {
            // stuff
            BindingList<SomeEntity> bindingList = new BindingList<Entity>(plainList); 
            return upCast(bindingList);
        }

Comment: As you can see, the method signature is aligned with the abstract method.

Comment: My bad, I forgot the `override`: Your function signature in SomeEntity needs to be: `public override BindingList<EntityBase> BindingList()`

Comment: Thanks. Being abstract, I could not think adding override.

Comment: "However, since SomeEntity is a decendant of EntityBase you can return a `BindingList<SomeEntity>` that is upcast to a `BindingList<EntityBase>`" No, I wouldn't expect that to work, any more than a cast from `List<string>` to `List<object>` would work. Generic variance just doesn't work that way.

Comment: You are right, Daisy. The upcast must be done explicitly. That is in my previous comment, and that way, it works.